# Maria DB Access Privileges

Tags: mariadb

I have created my Maria DB Instance under Centos 7 using the the following command

```
[username@localhost]$ sudo yum install mariadb-server
```

System Enabled and Started with the following Commands

```
sudo systemctl enable mariadb
sudo systemctl start mariadb
```

I have secured the installation with the following command

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

The Server was secured and invoked the mysql prompt using

```
mysql -u root -p
```

There is no problem. I am able to use this command to get into SQL Command

However when I am trying to load tables, i am getting the following error

> ERROR 1045 [28000]: Access Denied for user 'root@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)

Unable to load data. What could be the solution

Thanks

Sreeram

Comment: What exactly does it mean, "load tables", what SQL are you executing? And what does `SHOW GRANTS` say?

Comment: Paul, Thanks for your reply.. I was populating MariaDB with Sample Data. I could resolve the issue and populated the database with data. It is Single node localhost setup. The problem was root session does not know password to mysql root user. Hence I created .my.cnf and passed the required parameters. Since it is a local installation and exclusively used by me I have taken this step. I could populate my mariaDB with almost half a million records, spread over 6 tables.I have put secure rights to .my.cnf file..